# create array from mysql query php

Tags: php, arrays, mysql

I have a little problem that I don't understand. I have a db that has an owner and type (and more off course). I want to get a list of all the type values that has owner equal to the current user, but I get only two result

```
$sql = "SELECT type FROM cars WHERE owner='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' AND selling='0' ORDER BY id DESC "; 

 $result = mysql_query($sql,$con); 

 print_r(mysql_fetch_array($result));
```

prints out:

```
Array ( [0] => 18 [type] => 18 )
```

and

```
$sql = "SELECT type FROM cars WHERE owner='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."' AND selling='0' ";
```

prints out:

```
Array ( [0] => 16 [type] => 16 )
```

And the result should be something like 19, 19, 18, 17, 16 in an array. Thats all the types that has me as set as owner.

I have got this working now:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($result); $x++){
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  
 echo $row['type']; 
}
```

Here I print out all the values correctly, but I need to create an array with all the values. I though I could use array_push, but there most be a better way of doing it. I thought I would get all the type values with a simple mysql query.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Very often this is done in a `while` loop:

```
$types = array();

while(($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
    $types[] = $row['type'];
}
```

Have a look at the examples in the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).

The `mysql_fetch_*` methods will always get the *next* element of the result set:

> Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE  if there are no more rows.

That is why the `while` loops works. If there aren't any rows anymore `$row` will be `false` and the `while` loop exists.

It only seems that `mysql_fetch_array` gets more than one row, because by default it gets the result as [normal *and* as associative value](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php):

> By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.

Your example shows it best, you get the same value `18` and you can access it via `$v[0]` or `$v['type']`.

Answer (score 7):

```
THE CORRECT WAY ************************ THE CORRECT WAY

while($rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
array_pop($rows);  // pop the last row off, which is an empty row
```

Comment: YES! This is the CORRECT way.

Comment: He is not using mysqli he is using legacy mysql

Comment: Legacy mysql? You must mean deprecated Mysql.

Comment: Yep OLD mysql - OLDER than the version that the answer pertained to

Answer (score 3):

You do need to iterate through...

```
$typeArray = array();
$query = "select * from whatever";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ($result) {
    while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($results)) $typeArray[] = $record['type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$type_array = array();    
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $type_array[] = $row['type'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['type'];
}
```

Comment: His code is already doing this. He wants it to become an array. Echoing is not going to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make life easier using a wrapper, e.g. with ADODb:

```
$myarray=$db->GetCol("SELECT type FROM cars ".
    "WHERE owner=? and selling=0", 
    array($_SESSION['username']));
```

A good wrapper will do all your escaping for you too, making things easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to go look at the SQL Injection article on Wikipedia.  Look under the "Hexadecimal Conversion" part to find a small function to do your SQL commands and return an array with the information in it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

I wrote the dosql() function because I got tired of having my SQL commands executing all over the place, forgetting to check for errors, and being able to log all of my commands to a log file for later viewing if need be.  The routine is free for whoever wants to use it for whatever purpose.  I actually have expanded on the function a bit because I wanted it to do more but this basic function is a good starting point for getting the output back from an SQL call.