# Numeric and associative array usage

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$query = "SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER by ID LIMIT 3";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

From the PHP manual I have the above code and am wondering if anyone can help me understand it a little better.  Is this already multidimensional?  Can I access (for example) Row 5's Name and CountryCode by:

```
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[4][0], $row[4]["CountryCode"];
```

Or is it better to just use a numeric array and access it by $row[4][0], $row[4][1];
Any help would be fantastic.  I'm (obviously) a relative beginner at this.  Thank you!

Comment: The `mysqli_fetch_array` will return one row from the database results. If you wanted to see the contents of the `$row` array you could do `echo "<PRE>"; print_r($row);` after `mysqli_fetch_array` - it will probably help you understand the data structure.

Comment: You should also take a look at the accepted answer on - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415296/create-array-from-mysql-query-php?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `mysqli_fetch_array` with the `MYSQLI_BOTH` parameter is a single-dimensional array. The result represents a single row from the result set. Each row is an array that contains the retrieved data indexed in two ways:

- Numerical indices: 0, 1, 2 up to the number of columns in the result.
- String indices: "Name", "CountryCode" and what other fields you have there

The array looks like this:

```
$row Array (
    [0] => "MyName"
    [1] => "MyCountryCode"
    ["Name"] => "MyName"
    ["CountryCode"] => "MyCountryCode"
)
```

It's confusing to see both numerical and string indices in the same array, but the data is in fact correct. Unless you actually need the numerical indices, the string indices are much more comfortable to use. Therefore, the function `mysqli_fetch_assoc` would be more appropriate for this situation.

Still, these methods only return a single row from the result set. To get all the rows, you can use the following approach:

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    // do something with the row
}
```

EDIT: Adding the data to a multidimensional array:

```
$allResults = array();
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $allResults[] = $row;
}
```

Note that in most cases, you can get away with processing each row sequentially, without the need to store it for later.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for (sort of suspected it was non-multidimensional!) -- so in the "do something with the row" can you suggest a simple way to pack the data into a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't a multi dimensional array. In order to do something with all the results you should loop over the results like:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row["CountryCode"];
}
```

I always prefer to use names rather than numbers as they access the Queries column names directly so it's much easier to see what values are being pulled out. In this example, I know `CountryCode` will be printed out when I read the code, rather than some random index.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, because $row is a single dimensional array

```
/* associative and numeric array */
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["CountryCode"]);
```

And you can try with following

```
printf ("%s (%s)\n", $result[0]["CountryCode"]);
```

You have requested only 3 rows from the mysql, you can print the 4th row or above that with empty/ null values. It is a un-defined/ array limit exceeds error

> As you have used "MYSQLI_BOTH". So it will display the NULL Values. no
>   error will occur.